# How to restore wallet from wallet words after hard drive crash with no back up?

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery

If I lost wallets on hard drive crash, how do I restore with just my wallet words? Restoring data from back up is not working

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the Electrum tag to the question, I'll assume you're using Electrum.

When you first start up Electrum, you get the choice of creating a new seed or creating a wallet from an existing one. At that point you would select to enter your existing seed words, and it should recover your wallet.